# Returning range of different containers

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I have multiple containers with the same element type `T`. I would like to select one of the containers depending on a enum.

I tried something like this:

```cpp
auto range = [category,system]() -> auto {
    switch(category) {
        case sound_category::voice:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->dialogue_voices); // could be std::array
        case sound_category::mono:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->mono_voices); // could be std::vector
        case sound_category::music:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->music_voices); // could be std::list
        default:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->sfx_voices); // could be std::deque
    }
}();
```

but that will result in a compiler error, since the deduced type in the cases is different.

Is there some way to achieve that?

Comment: You could always copy the stuff you need to a `std::vector` and return *that*.

Comment: @KamilCuk The **value** type of the containers (sfx_voices, mono_voices etc) is the same and I am only interested in the values/references to these values

Comment: Return a `std::span` of the array you want?

Comment: `std::span` is the way to go. Changing the return type of the lambda to `std::span<T>` and return `std::span(system->...)` should work for the purpose.

Comment: I figured a `std::span` would work. But would it be possible to handle different containers `std::vector<T>` in one enum case, `std::list<T>` in another ?

Comment: @Raildex A `span` only support contiguous containers, so you couldn't mix a `list` into this.  Depending on your use case a `std::list` can be replaced by a `std::vector` and you'll get better performance: https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html

Comment: @Raildex Is `category` a compile time know value?

Comment: @NathanOliver while a span could potentially solve my issue **now**. It won't work if I want to switch out the container in a later development stage (to a non-contiguous one). This is not a question about "performance" or "array vs vector vs list vs deque". My goal is to have a generic way to get a view from a collection selected at runtime.

Comment: @Raildex I have as well, feel free to roll back, but I figured removing all mention that these are arrays currently isn't needed since you want a generic solution.

Comment: @Jarod42 wow. `any_view` **is** magic. Can you make an answer?

Comment: @Raildex `any_view` is not magic, it use type erasure and comes with performance penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) has [any_view](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1any__view.html) for type erasure view.

So it would be something like:

```
auto range = [category,system]() -> ranges::v3::any_view<Voice>
{
    switch(category) {
        case sound_category::voice:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->dialogue_voices); // could be std::array
        case sound_category::mono:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->mono_voices); // could be std::vector
        case sound_category::music:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->music_voices); // could be std::list
        default:
            return std::ranges::views::all (system->sfx_voices); // could be std::deque
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subrange from two iterators.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <array>
int main() {
    std::array<int, 2> a;
    std::array<int, 3> b;
    auto c = std::ranges::subrange<int*>(a.begin(), a.end());
    c = std::ranges::subrange<int*>(b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

Comment: That does not compile. https://godbolt.org/z/8fTbTc9dW

Comment: Compiles on gcc, no idea about msvc. Doing explicit template type `std::ranges::subrange<int*>` works fine. Could be `std::range<>::iterator` is more special on msvc, dunno

Comment: Doesn't compile on clang and msvc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of something like:

```cpp
auto range = [category,system]() -> auto {
    switch(category) {
        case sound_category::voice:
            // ...
    }
}();
// stuff with range
```

You can use a visitor pattern:

```cpp
auto visitor = [&](const auto& range) {
    // stuff with range
};
switch (category) {
    case sound_category::voice:
        return visitor(system->dialogue_voices);
    case sound_category::mono:
        return visitor(system->mono_voices);
    // ...
}
```